# Configuração baseada em código - EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle, entity-framework-6

Estou a alguns dias tentando implementar uma conexão com um banco de dados Oracle 11g utilizando a configuração baseada em código do EF6, porém, nada do que fiz até agora parece funcionar.

Atualmente esta é a minha implementação:

[image: DbConfiguration]

[image: Context]

## App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CsvHelper" publicKeyToken="8c4959082be5c823" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SharpSnmpLib" publicKeyToken="4c00852d3788e005" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FluentFTP" publicKeyToken="f4af092b1d8df44f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-19.2.2.0" newVersion="19.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="BouncyCastle.Crypto" publicKeyToken="0e99375e54769942" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.3.0" newVersion="1.8.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.122.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.18.3" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Este é o erro que está sendo apresentado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não deveria estar utilizando a string de conexão do seu arquivo de configuração?

Comment: Não, na verdade esta implementação é justamente para não precisar adicionar isso no arquivo de configuração.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based

Comment: E quando as credenciais mudarem, você vai recompilar e redistribuir todo o seu software?

Comment: Na verdade este software em particular, não tem uma grande lista de distribuição. Ele é utilizado em apenas uma máquina.

Então a resposta é sim, caso as credenciais sejam alteradas ele será recompilado e redistribuído.